# Cutting image corners with CSS clip-path with a fixed angle

Tags: html, css, clip-path

i want to cut my image corners by **45 degrees** like the image below with `clip-pat`h,i want values by percentage, I just need values for clip-path,

```css
#div img:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 0%, 9.52% 98.91%, 89.95% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/400/300.jpg">
</div>
```

[image: example image]

image is just for example because angles are not exactly 45 degrees, I need cutting be done exactly by 45 degrees, and my code is not 45 degrees

Comment: @Paulie_D its very simple, it does not require REALLY an example, i just don't know the values for "clip-path: polygon(x% y%,......)", i don't know how many dots i need and what values are!

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you but that's not what i want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mask instead of `clip-path` and you can easily have your 45deg

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask:
     linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 50%,transparent 50%) top left ,
     linear-gradient(-225deg,#fff 50%,transparent 50%) top right;
  -webkit-mask-size:2000px 2000px; /* width = height and big enough to consider all the cases */
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-in;
  mask:
     linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 50%,transparent 50%) top left,
     linear-gradient(-225deg,#fff 50%,transparent 50%) top right;
  mask-size:2000px 2000px; /* width = height and big enough to consider all the cases */
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-composite: intersect;
  
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/500/100" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/700/100" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/500/200" >
```

Another idea using `clip-path` that will **only** work if the image will always have its width bigger than its height:

```css
img {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,calc(100% - 2000px) 2000px,2000px 2000px);
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/500/100" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/700/100" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/500/200" >
```

Comment: very nice, it works great, sorry to bother you but do you have any idea how can i make this work with clip:rect, i need to somehow crop image for different widths according to user's desire and this works for whole img width and not inside clipped area

Comment: @fardad I don't really understand, can be more clear? show me an example?